# How to make JavaFX gradually changing effect on a Image

Tags: javafx-8

In my JavaFX application I have a `ImageView` on the stage. I wanted to add both effects `Glow` and `Sepia`, and both should be gradually increasing (0 to 1) within duration 5 sec.

How do I do this with code?
Both effects should be applied in parallel. Would it make the animation slower?

Comment: Have you tried using a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html)?

Comment: @James_D With timeline I was stucked in dividing the effect values 0-1 for 5 seconds equally. I'm not familiar with `TimeLine`.  Couldn't find any example too.

Comment: Just see the javadocs (linked in first comment). They are pretty complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Timeline` with one `KeyFrame` at the start and one at the end. For each `KeyFrame` just set the value of each effect:

```
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                new KeyValue(glow.levelProperty(), 0),
                new KeyValue(sepia.levelProperty(), 0)),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5),
                new KeyValue(glow.levelProperty(), 1),
                new KeyValue(sepia.levelProperty(),1))
    );
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.effect.Glow;
import javafx.scene.effect.SepiaTone;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimatedEffects extends Application {

    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width/public/thumbnails/image/nh-charon-neutral-bright-release.jpg?itok=20aE3TAH";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(IMAGE_URL, 400, 400, true, true));
        Glow glow = new Glow(0);
        SepiaTone sepia = new SepiaTone(0);
        sepia.setInput(glow);
        image.setEffect(sepia);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                    new KeyValue(glow.levelProperty(), 0),
                    new KeyValue(sepia.levelProperty(), 0)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5),
                    new KeyValue(glow.levelProperty(), 1),
                    new KeyValue(sepia.levelProperty(),1))
        );

        Button effectButton = new Button("Add effect");
        effectButton.setOnAction(e -> timeline.play());

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(image, null, null, effectButton, null);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(effectButton, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(effectButton, new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```